# In an array with two objects, how can I be getting an out of bounds exception at (1)?

Tags: java

I'm getting an "ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1" error, but only when "q" is entered to exit the program.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ParseStrings {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
  Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
  Scanner  inSS = null;
  String userInfo = "";
  String firstWord = "";
  String secondWord = "";
  String[] names = {"",""};


  System.out.println("Enter input string: ");
  userInfo = scnr.nextLine();

  boolean isFound = userInfo.contains(",");

  if (isFound == false) {
        System.out.println("Error: No comma in string");
        System.out.println("Enter input string: ");

        userInfo = scnr.nextLine();
        isFound = userInfo.contains(",");
     }

     while (isFound) {

        names = userInfo.split(",");

        firstWord = names[0];
        secondWord = names[1]; //<----- LINE 33

        System.out.println("First word: " + firstWord.trim());
        System.out.println("Second word: " + secondWord.trim());
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("");

        System.out.println("Enter input string: ");
        userInfo = scnr.nextLine();

     }

      if (userInfo == "q") {
           System.exit(0);
      }
   return;
   }
}
```

The intent of the program is to separate strings/lines consisting of two words, separated by a ",". This part works perfectly, but the program fails when "q" is entered to exit.

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
    at ParseStrings.main(ParseStrings.java:33)

Comment: Because `names[1]` doesn't exist in this scenario. This is pretty easy to solve. Think it thorugh

Comment: If `1` is out of bounds, the array obviously does **not** have two elements but is either empty or has only one element.

Comment: Not sure why you think it has two elements. You do `split` and get the resulting array back. If your input did not contain a comma, like `"hello world"`, the resulting array will only have one element.

Comment: you expect it to have 2 elements, why? You overwrite the initial `{"",""}`. `userInfo ` is overwritten at the end of the loop and simply doesnt contain a `,`.

Comment: If q is entered, the while loop should stop executing was my thought process.

Comment: Thank you all, I will delete this.

Comment: Check your loop condition then. Do you ever update it?

Comment: At the end of the while loop, would entering q NOT cause it to re-enter into the while loop? I think this is the part I'm misunderstanding.

Comment: Also in case `userInfo` equals "q", you split the string and try to access the second element (which does not exist). Therefore, check for "q" before splitting. BTW, string comparision is done by means of `equals` instead of `==`

Comment: Your loop is defined as `while (isFound)`, but since you never update `isFound` anywhere in the loop it will keep on looping. A simple solution would probably be to add `isFound = userInfo.contains(",");` at the end of the loop, but you may benefit from a larger refactoring.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here :

```
names = userInfo.split(",");
```

When `userInfo` contains only `q`, `names` will be `{"q"}`, an array of only one element.

Hence, `names[1]`, which is the second element of `names` does not exist.

Hence the `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

You might refactor it like this :

```
while (isFound) {
  if (userInfo.equals("q")) { // btw, notice the 'equals' instead of ==
    System.exit(0);
  }
  names = userInfo.split(",");
  firstWord = names[0];
  secondWord = names[1]; 
  [...]
```

Comment: Thank you. I thought once q was entered, the isFound would equate to false and continue beyond that loop.

Answer (score 0):

You should add this: `isFound = userInfo.contains(",");` at the end of the while code block.

The issue seems to be the fact that the while loop will never stop.